# UILabel changing position

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

for some reason the label in my uitableviewcell changes position when I have an activity indicator or something like that load on the right.. is there anyway to stop this?

**cell one is having the problem in this view**

[image]

**Cell one and two are having the issue in this view**

[image]

what happens is that when I have something loading in the background I have a uiactivity indicator, once thats played the labels in my custom cells move over to the right. if there is no Disclosure Indicator then you will see in the second image cell two moves right over to the right.. but if there is a Disclosure Indicator it moves over only a little bit.. other wise the labels will load in the correct position, but as soon as some type of cell indicatory happens then it throws the labels out of alignment.

Comment: mark your label that is having problem. and how have you added this label..custom cell or through code...??

Comment: I updated my question to identify the cells..

Comment: have you made custom cell and how are you adding this label?

Comment: yep, I made a custom cell in interface builder, and the label is added in interface builder. I edit everything programaticaly (i.e by edit i mean just change the value of the text in the label etc) nothing to do with positioning.. its like when ever an indicator happens in the cell it totally messes with the alignment..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your label's `autoresizingMask` includes `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin`. If you're creating cells from storyboard/nib file, go to XCode's Size Inspector view and change the `Autosizing` to look like this:

[image]

Comment: ahhh.. I tried a couple of different combinations before this that didnt work.. this worked perfectly tho!!! thanks very much.

Comment: Is there a way to have them move to the left when I swipe to delete? (i.e. so that it moves when the delete button comes up and is not being covered..?) or is it one or the other?

Comment: Yes it is one or the other. Maybe add the activity indicator as a subview instead of an accessory view, then keep your label's `autoresizingMask` as it was before